# Subset a data frame by Row and Column totals

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I am new to Python and trying to subset a data frame of user-movie ratings first by Row Totals and next by Column Totals. The filter by column totals is taking hours to complete and so I was wondering if you could provide me some pointers to optimize the code.

```
  data_cols = ['user_id','movie_id','rating']
  data = pd.read_csv('netflix_data/TrainingRatings.txt', sep=',', names=data_cols)
  utrain = (data.sort_values('user_id'))
  print(utrain.tail())

  Movie_Ratings = utrain.pivot_table(index = ['user_id'],columns =    ['movie_id'], values = ['rating'], aggfunc = lambda x:x)
  Movie_Ratings.head()
  Movie_Ratings = Movie_Ratings.fillna(0)

  #Filter by column totals
  Movie_Ratings.loc[len(Movie_Ratings)] = [Movie_Ratings[col].sum() for col in Movie_Ratings.columns]

  ##Following portion is taking the maximum amount of time
  x = Movie_Ratings.loc[len(Movie_Ratings)-1]
  for col in Movie_Ratings.columns:
      if(x[col] <= 500):
          Movie_Ratings.drop(col,axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can use [`DataFrame.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) only:

```
Movie_Ratings.loc[len(Movie_Ratings)] = Movie_Ratings.sum()
```

And then filter without loops:

```
np.random.seed(100)
Movie_Ratings = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(250, size=(5,5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))
print (Movie_Ratings)
     A    B    C    D    E
0    8   24   67  103   87
1   79  176  138   94  180
2   98   53   66  226   14
3   34  241  240   24  143
4  228  107   60   58  144

Movie_Ratings.loc[len(Movie_Ratings)] = Movie_Ratings.sum()
Movie_Ratings = Movie_Ratings.loc[:, ~(Movie_Ratings.iloc[-1] <= 500)]
#Orchange condition to > and remove ~ for invert condition
#Movie_Ratings = Movie_Ratings.loc[:, (Movie_Ratings.iloc[-1] > 500)]
print (Movie_Ratings)
     B    C    D    E
0   24   67  103   87
1  176  138   94  180
2   53   66  226   14
3  241  240   24  143
4  107   60   58  144
5  601  571  505  568
```

Explanation:

```
print (Movie_Ratings.iloc[-1])
A    447
B    601
C    571
D    505
E    568
Name: 5, dtype: int64

print (Movie_Ratings.iloc[-1]<= 500)
A     True
B    False
C    False
D    False
E    False
Name: 5, dtype: bool

print (~(Movie_Ratings.iloc[-1]<= 500))
A    False
B     True
C     True
D     True
E     True
Name: 5, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Can you explain the second line?

Comment: Sure, give me a sec